# Show $\langle f,g\rangle$ is not an inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $X = C[−1,1]$ be the space of continuous functions $f : [−1,1] → \mathbb R$. For $f,g ∈ X$ deﬁne

$$\langle f,g\rangle =\int_0^1 f(t)g(t)dt$$

If I choose $f(t)=-t$ and $g(t)=1$, then $\langle f,g\rangle$ would be negative so it wont be an inner product.

Is this correct?

Comment: Inner product can take negative values as well. This fails to be an inner product because it is degenerate.

Comment: If $\langle f,g\rangle = 1$, then $\langle -f,g\rangle = -1$. Inner products always take on negative values unless the space is $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect. $\langle f,g \rangle$ is allowed to take *any value*, but $\langle f,f \rangle$ must be non-negative.  Try to come up with an example of two vectors whose *dot-product* is negative, noting that the dot-product is the prototypical inner product.

The property of inner products that fails here is that
$$
\|f\|^2 = \langle f,f \rangle = 0 \iff f = 0
$$
try to find a non-zero (continuous) $f$ whose norm is zero.

---

Answer (as given by asker in the comments):
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & x \in [-1,0)\\
0 & x \in [0,1]
\end{cases}
$$
is such a function.

Comment: What if I choose $f(x)=x^{-1}$, then $\langle f,f \rangle = \int_0^1 x^{-2} dx=-1$?

Comment: @snowman first of all, you computed the integral incorrectly; that integral diverges.  Second, $f(x) = x^{-1}$ is **not** continuous on $[-1,1]$, so it is not a valid $f$ for this problem.

Comment: @snowman note that any non-negative function will have a non-negative integral (since any area under the curve is positive), and $[f(x)]^2$ will always be non-negative.

Comment: my bad... So I guess we can think of some composite function right?

Comment: @snowman I'm not sure what you mean by a "composite function".  Do you mean a [piecewise function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise)? If so, then that is the right general idea, but of course the answer lies in the details.

Comment: yeah piecewise, f=x if x is -1 to 0 inclusive and 0 otherwise. That works right? since <f,f>=0 but that does not imply f was 0 since f is not 0 when x is between [-1,0).

Comment: @snowman Yep, that will do it.  Note also that this function is continuous, as it should be (since we are looking for an example in $C[-1,1]$).